Next.js application is there any better way to do server side rendering
I'm doing server side rendering in my next.js applicaton. This component just returns html. Is there any better way?
import Feature from 'components/home/Feature/Feature';
import HeroArea from 'components/home/HeroArea/HeroArea';
import HeroFeatures from 'components/home/HeroFeatures/HeroFeatures';
import Newsletter from 'components/home/Newsletter/Newsletter';
import PopularCryptocurrencies from 'components/home/PopularCryptocurrencies/PopularCryptocurrencies';
import Testimonial from 'components/home/Testimonial/Testimonial';
import SponsorCard from 'components/sponsor_card/SponserCard';
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

import { getTranslations } from '../utils/translations';
interface IndexType {
  popularCryptoData: {
    current_price: number;
    high_24h: number;
    id: string;
    low_24h: number;
    market_cap: number;
    market_cap_rank: 1;
    name: string;
    price_change_24h: number;
    symbol: string;
    total_volume: number;
    image: string;
  }[];
}

const Home: NextPage<any> = ({ heroFeatures, feature, testimonial, t }) => {
  return (
    <div data-theme='dark'>
      <main className='relative overflow-hidden'>
        <div className="bg-[url('../public/images/DarkBlueBG.svg')] bg-cover    ">
          <HeroArea />
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: heroFeatures }} />

          <PopularCryptocurrencies />

          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: feature }} />
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: testimonial }} />
          <Newsletter />
          <div className='block absolute'>
            <SponsorCard />
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ locale }: any) => {
  const t = getTranslations(locale);

  const heroFeatures = renderToString(<HeroFeatures t={t} />);
  const feature = renderToString(<Feature t={t} />);
  const testimonial = renderToString(<Testimonial t={t} />);

  return {
    props: {
      heroFeatures,
      feature,
      testimonial,
      t,
    },
  };
};

export default Home;


This is my Home page. i am using react/dom-server.renderToString  and dangerouslySetInnerHTML and _html
It is doing server side rendering properly.But is there any better way

Am I missing something or why are you doing this at all in Next.js?
Can't you simply put your HeroFeatures, Testimonial, and Feature components inside Home's tree diectly? Doing that will still render your Home component on the server. If you're worried about the t function, you can create it from within the Home component instead of doing it from getServerSideProps.

dangerouslySetInnerHTML is dangerous, and should be avoided.
You should not pass around rendered HTML code (or components) as props, if you can avoid it.
I suggest to return only t from getServerSideProps, and render the components in Home. Next.js should still render the components server side (if it is set up accordingly).
E.g. change:
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: heroFeatures }} />

to:
<div><HeroFeatures t={t} /><div>

(I assume you can also omit the <div>.)
